# Searching for outdated CMS versions on server

Tags: web-hosting, search, joomla, cms

I'm interested if there is a way to search for all outdated installations of CMS systems on my server ( RHEL).  For example, is there a way to automatically search for all old versions of Joomla CMS that would need updating ?

Answer (score 1):

Like, find(1) ?(*) (unless you are using a packaged version. In which case u should not have more than ONE up-to-date version of the software).

(*) As in

```
find / -path '*/joomla/*' -name 'version.php' | xargs fgrep 'var $RELEASE'
```

Comment: How would you use find to do this ?

Comment: find / -path '*/joomla/*' -name 'version.php'  | xargs fgrep 'var $RELEASE'

Comment: I found it fascinating that you thought your (non) answer was worth the effort to write. Not everyone would have a solution for this question but many can spot a poor answer when they see one. If you edit your answer to include the find command you put in the comment above then (if they choose to do so) the down voters could remove their votes right now they can't.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm  getting your point?

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't RHEL use RPM as its package manager. In that case you could query RPM for this information. Here's a [link to some information about that](http://www.tfug.org/helpdesk/linux/rpm.html).

Comment: Well the question was specifically about searching for installations. Presumably the questioner knows whether or not they are the kind of person that installs things via a package manager or not. There are definitely RPMs available for Joomla. I don't see why you think this is a bad answer.